# Regex match returing 'none' while findall & search work

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Below is a code I am trying out (to learn regex myself).

```
a = "This island is beautiful"
reg = re.compile(r'\bis\b')
print(reg.match(a))
print(reg.findall(a))
print(reg.search(a).group(0))
```

The output of the code is

```
None
['is']
is
```

As you can see, `findall` & `search` found the word 'is' in the string but `match` returns `None`.

Shouldn't `match` also find the word 'is'? I am confused.

Comment: Yes, but `re.match` matches *only* at the start of a string. You want `re.search` instead.

Comment: `match(str[,pos[,endpos]])` looks at `pos` which defaults to 0 in string for start of `str` and can't match it so gives `None`.
`print(reg.match(a,12))` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the string

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match